# Date issue with scatter and LinearRegression

Tags: python, date, pandas

I have two issues and I believe both are released to the date format.

I have a cvs with dates and values:

```
2012-01-03 00:00:00     95812    
2012-01-04 00:00:00    101265 
... 
2016-10-21 00:00:00     93594
```

after i load it with `read_csv` I'm trying to parse the date with:

```
X.Dated = pd.to_datetime(X.Dated, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', errors='raise')
```

I also tried with:

```
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
X = pd.read_csv('sales.csv', parse_dates=['Dated'], date_parser=dateparse)
```

and `infer_datetime_format` argument.

All of them seems to work fine because when I print it out the date looks like: `2012-01-03`.

The issue appears when I'm trying to plot the data on chart, this line:

```
ax.scatter(X.Dated, X.Val, c='green', marker='.')
```

gives me an error:

```
TypeError: invalid type promotion
```

Also when I try to use it with LinearRegression() algorithm the fit command 
works fine but the score and predict gives me this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('<M8[ns]') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

I tried many things to fix it but with no luck.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ax.scatter` (at the moment) does not accept Pandas Series, but it can accept a list of Pandas Timestamps (e.g. `X['Dated'].tolist()`), or NumPy array of dtype `datetime64[ns]` (e.g. `X['Dated'].values`):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = pd.DataFrame({'Dated': [pd.Timestamp('2012-01-03 00:00:00'),
                            pd.Timestamp('2012-01-04 00:00:00'),
                            pd.Timestamp('2016-10-21 00:00:00')],
                  'Val': [95812, 101265, 93594]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# ax.scatter(X['Dated'].tolist(), X['Val'], c='green', marker='.', s=200)
ax.scatter(X['Dated'].values, X['Val'], c='green', marker='.', s=200)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

[Under the hood, the `ax.scatter` method calls](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L3990)

```
x = self.convert_xunits(x)
y = self.convert_yunits(y)
```

to handle date-like inputs. `convert_xunits` converts NumPy datetime64 arrays to Matplotlib datenums, but it converts Pandas timeseries to NumPy datetime64 array.

So, when a Pandas timeseries is passed as input to `ax.scatter`, the code ends up failing when [this line is reached](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L4056):

```
offsets = np.dstack((x, y))
```

`np.dstack` tries to promote the dtypes of its inputs to one common dtype. If `x` has dtype `datetime64[ns]` and `y` has dtype `float64`, then

```
TypeError: invalid type promotion
```

is raised since there is no native NumPy dtype which is compatible with both.

Comment: Thanks it helps, I can display it on the graph now. That answers first part of my question.Do you know why I have the other error: Cannot cast array data from dtype('<M8[ns]') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'? I tried to pass Timestamps instead but It gives me an error that it only accept string or numbers.

Comment: @Greg: I added a bit of explanation about where the error comes from. Ultimately, a TypeError is raised when np.dstack tries to combine the x and y inputs into a single array (with a common dtype). Since `datetime64[ns]` and `float` dtypes do not have a compatible common dtype, a TypeError is raised.