# "TypeError: invalid type promotion" for scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, plot

This code is giving me an error for some reason, and I can't figure out why.

[Kaggle: Blue Book for Bulldozers - TrainAndValid.csv](https://www.kaggle.com/c/bluebook-for-bulldozers/data?select=TrainAndValid.csv)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.read_csv("bluebook-for-bulldozers/TrainAndValid.csv",
                low_memory=False,
                parse_dates=["saledate"])


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(df["saledate"][:1000], df["SalePrice"][:1000])
```

df["saledate"] is of type '<M8[ns]' and df["SalePrice"] is of type float64 in case that's of any relevance. I'm not sure why this code isn't working since I'm following an online tutorial and wrote the exact same code.

Here are the first ten elements of df["saledate"] and df["SalePrice"], respectively:

```
# read in with
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')


saledate,SalePrice
2006-11-16,66000.0
2004-03-26,57000.0
2004-02-26,10000.0
2011-05-19,38500.0
2009-07-23,11000.0
2008-12-18,26500.0
2004-08-26,21000.0
2005-11-17,27000.0
2009-08-27,21500.0
2007-08-09,65000.0
2008-08-21,24000.0
2006-08-24,22500.0
2005-10-20,36000.0
2006-01-26,30500.0
2006-01-03,28000.0
2006-11-16,19000.0
2007-06-14,13500.0
2010-01-28,9500.0
2006-03-09,12500.0
2005-11-17,11500.0
```

Comment: See [Difference between data type 'datetime64' and '<M8'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206612/difference-between-data-type-datetime64ns-and-m8ns) and see [Fixing common date annoyances](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/recipes/common_date_problems.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Date issue with scatter and LinearRegression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40220076/date-issue-with-scatter-and-linearregression)

Comment: Always include the entire Traceback and [Provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example (e.g. code, data, errors) as text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I added some details to make it reproducible. Thanks for linking "Date issue with scatter and LinearRegression", but as I stated in the question, this code is not mine. I was simply repeating what I saw in an online tutorial. Why do I get an error when the online tutorial doesn't?

Comment: My second comment tells you how to resolve this issue. The first 3 links explain "why" in various ways.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I still couldn't get it to work. I tried converting df["saledate"] into an object array (as per the second link) but that didn't fix anything. I also tried the suggestion in the last link. Basically, I created an empty list "tempsaledate" and added each element of df["saledate"] to it after converting that element to a timestamp. I then tried plotting ax.scatter(tempsaledate[:1000], df["SalePrice"][:1000]). Now I'm getting a different error "float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'"

Comment: With the dataset from Kaggle, I am not able to reproduce this error.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Yes it is from Kaggle. The instructor in the video does not get an error either. I have no idea why I keep getting it.